# Getdate between times

Tags: t-sql, getdate

Sorry if this has been asked somewhere all ready but I've struggled to find the answer! I have a date time field with is a date time stamp on activity.

I need to have a query that only brings back information for data that's between today's date and events between 08:00 and 10:00.My brains says it should be straight forward but i cant suss it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using BETWEEN?

Comment: Its more the query of how to use the between Getdate() 08:00:00 and getdate() 10:00:00 . I need it to get the current date and only return data between those two times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME> WHERE EVENTS_DATE BETWEEN
DATEADD(hour, 8, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) 
AND 
DATEADD(hour, 10, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

If you use a variable in TSQL then store today's date in that

```
DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())
```

Comment: perfect!! Works a treat!! Thanks Indoknight!

Answer (score 2):

To get a particular point in time, I tend to use the `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` pattern. It can look a bit unwieldy, but performs quite nicely, and once you're used to seeing it, it becomes more readable:

```
SELECT * --TODO - Pick columns
FROM Activities
WHERE OccurredAt BETWEEN
     DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20010101',GETDATE()),'2001-01-01T08:00:00') AND
     DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20010101',GETDATE()),'2001-01-01T10:00:00')
```

Here I'm using it twice. It just relies on the relationship between two date constants that you pick because they exhibit the features that you want. So here:

```
DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20010101',GETDATE()),'2001-01-01T08:00:00')
```

I'm calculating the number of (whole) days that have elapsed between 1st January 2001 and right now. I'm then adding that (whole) number of days onto 08:00 on the 1st January 2001 - which will, logically, produce 08:00 today.

Comment: This works well +1. But, not sure how if does when the default date format changes.

Comment: @Indoknight - the date/datetime constants I've shown are formatted as they are because they're guaranteed to work no matter what formatting settings are in effect (I.e. for a date without a time, `YYYYMMDD` is guaranteed that interpretation. For a date *with* a time, you have to move to including dashes/colons and using a `T` to separate the date and time)

Comment: Any reason to use `T` instead of space before time? ODBC canonical form uses space.

Comment: @Aryadev - `set language british; select DATEPART(month,CONVERT(datetime,'2001-01-02 08:00:00'));`. Result: `2`. (on versions before the literal gets converted to a `datetime2` rather than a `datetime`, you can miss out the `CONVERT()` call). This is despite the fact that no-one in britain (to my knowledge) would expect that to be interpreted as the 1st February.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ...
where dateColumn between 
  convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 120) + 'T08:00:00' 
  and convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 120) + 'T10:00:00'
```